# extracting values from list of tuples (in this case just one tuple in the list)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, tuples

I'm working in python GAE.

Can't figure out why I can't extract values from my tuple using `[index]`.  From the logs, I can see that I do have a value in my `leveloneAdd` variable e.g. (`'english'`, `'subject'`) - but then when I'm looping through my tuple of 1, I'm getting empty in my variable `tag` and `htype` - when I'm expecting the `tag = 'english'` and the `htype = 'subject'`.

Anyone have any thoughts?

```
for each in leveloneAdd:
    tag = each[0]
    htype = each[1]
    q1 = Level_1_Headings.all().filter("name1 =",tag).filter("heading_type =",htype).get()
```

So I did the repr in the logs as Martijn suggested and here are my logs:
thanks for all your input!  love this board - here are my logs using suggestion from Martijn --- I think it is interpreting the whole thing like a string ---

```
INFO     2013-01-14 19:28:17,030 main.py:291] each is ('math', 'subject')
INFO     2013-01-14 19:28:17,030 main.py:292] u"('math', 'subject')"
INFO     2013-01-14 19:28:17,030 main.py:294] tag is (
INFO     2013-01-14 19:28:17,030 main.py:296] heading type is '
```

It looks like the string is being viewed as a string?  How do I convert this to reading as a true tuple.  Here is my original code where the tuple was supposed to be created (it then goes to client and then back as this as shown in the log.)

for x in h1:
     listone.append((str(x.name1),str(x.heading_type)))

The values above are in an input select drop box form
AND then from server side python - i get the values by
    leveloneAdd = (self.request.get_all("list_uno[]"))

Sorry if these seem basic questions, I'm a beginner trying to get better!!

Comment: Log `repr(leveloneAdd)` instead to verify that it is, indeed, a tuple.

Comment: if `leveloneAdd == ('english', 'subject')` then `each` would be first 'english' and then 'subject'.

Comment: Exactly what @F.C. said.

Comment: You should not do for each in. Just try to access them directly. leveloneAdd[0] if there is will be english and leveloneAdd[1] will be subject

Comment: This would solve for this case, but want to accommodate instances where there will be multiple values (or tuples).  e.g.   ('math','subject'),('gym,'subject'), ('music', 'work), etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `leveloneAdd == ('english', 'subject')` then it is not a list of tuples, it is just a tuple so `each` in every iteration of the loop would take a string as a value.

Your code would work fine if `leveloneAdd == [('english', 'subject')]` that is a list with a tuple inside.

Your best option, if you can, would be to fix the code so leveloneAdd is always a list of tuples, if you can't do that then you would have to fix it by making leveloneAdd a list when it is a tuple with two strings in it. Be careful, test with all your inputs because is easy to make an error when dealing with that kind of conversions.

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get_all) says `get_all` should return a list, maybe it returns a list only when there is more than one argument. If that is the case you could convert the value to a list if it is a string:

```
if isinstance(leveloneAdd, basestring):
    leveloneAdd = [leveloneAdd]
```

After that just split the values of leveloneAdd with ','

Also adjust your Javascript to avoid the extra characters like "(" and "'"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (tag, htype) in leveloneAdd:
    # stuff
```

If it's not a tuple, you'll get something like "Too many values to unpack" errors.

---

I misread the OP.

When I run into problems like this, I usually try something like:

```
for thing in list:
    try:
        (tag, htype) = thing
    except:
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
```

Then you'll get the debugger and you can see if 'thing' is what you think it is.

---

As per OP, the 'thing' isn't a tuple but a unicode string. To solve your problem, cast to a string, and then split the string. Code follows:

```
thing = u'(a,b)'
[tag, htype] = str(thing).lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split(',')
```

This assumes you're always expecting a tuple of two entries.

Comment: That won't solve the OP problem; it's a nicer way to get the values, but won't tell the OP why there are empty values.

Answer (score 1):

What F.C. says is true.

I'm a little confused by the single-element vs tuple question. If the basic problems is just detecting whether you've got simple values or tuples as elements of `leveloneAdd`, perhaps you would consider having `listoneAdd` as a list of tuples, even if the thing you are adding is a single element.  That way, when you pull an element out of the list, you will always know that you can index into it:

```
listoneAdd = [('one',), ('foot',), ('three', 'pigs')]
for element in listoneAdd:
    print "element is " + str(element)
    for i in range(0,len(element)):
        print "    do something with value " + element[i]`
```

yielding:

```
element is ('one',)
    do something with value one
element is ('foot',)
    do something with value foot
element is ('three', 'pigs')
    do something with value three
    do something with value pigs`
```